# Floating for least blank

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

Please refer to http://lrin.tk/float_problem.htm.

Here's how my page looks like:

`````````````
   +-----------------------+ +---------------------------+ +--------------+ 
   |]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]| |___________________________| |::::::::::::::| 
   |]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]| |___________________________| |::::::::::::::| 
   |]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]| |___________________________| |::::::::::::::| 
   |]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]| |___________________________| |::::::::::::::| 
   |]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]| |___________________________| |::::::::::::::| 
   +-----------------------+ |___________________________| +--------------+ 
                             |___________________________|                  
                             |___________________________|                  
                             |___________________________|                  
              [2]            |___________________________|       [1]         
                             |___________________________|                  
                             |___________________________|                  
                             +---------------------------+                  
       +--------------+ +------------+ +----------+ +---------------------+ 
       |**************| |````````````| |==========| |"""""""""""""""""""""| 
       |**************| |````````````| |==========| |"""""""""""""""""""""| 
    [3]|**************| |````````````| |==========| |"""""""""""""""""""""| 
       |**************| |````````````| |==========| |"""""""""""""""""""""| 
       |**************| |````````````| |==========| |"""""""""""""""""""""| 
       +--------------+ +------------+ +----------+ +---------------------+ 
                                              +---------------------------+ 
                                              |{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{| 
                                              |{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{| 
                                              |{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{| 
                                              |{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{| 
                                              |{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{| 
                                              |{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{| 
                                              +---------------------------+
`````````````

- All `div`s' height are fixed to a certain value. In the HTML file, 200px.
- Actually, the `___________`-striped `div` is fixed(not CSS-ually `position:fixed`) on the upper-right side.

When the window is re-sized *(with a threshold of 20px)*, a `reArrange` function is called.
Now the code just simply shuffle the `div`s, so the inflexible browser just leaves area #1 and area #2 empty, not to mention a little slice of area #3.

However the `div`s are arranged, I would like it to fit the most areas of a line.
Which means,a new line is started only when **the current line has no space to hold any** (actually "the most narrow one") **of the un-ordered `div`s**.

So in the example, the ideal result should be:

`````````````
 +--------------+ +--------------+ +---------------------------+ +------------+ 
 |::::::::::::::| |**************| |___________________________| |````````````| 
 |::::::::::::::| |**************| |___________________________| |````````````| 
 |::::::::::::::| |**************| |___________________________| |````````````| 
 |::::::::::::::| |**************| |___________________________| |````````````| 
 |::::::::::::::| |**************| |___________________________| |````````````| 
 +--------------+ +--------------+ |___________________________| +------------+ 
         +-----------------------+ |___________________________|   +----------+ 
         |]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]| |___________________________|   |==========| 
         |]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]| |___________________________|   |==========| 
         |]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]| |___________________________|   |==========| 
         |]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]| |___________________________|   |==========| 
         |]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]| |___________________________|   |==========| 
         +-----------------------+ +---------------------------+   +----------+ 
                          +---------------------+ +---------------------------+ 
                          |"""""""""""""""""""""| |{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{| 
                          |"""""""""""""""""""""| |{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{| 
                          |"""""""""""""""""""""| |{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{| 
                          |"""""""""""""""""""""| |{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{| 
                          |"""""""""""""""""""""| |{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{| 
                          +---------------------+ |{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{| 
                                                  +---------------------------+
`````````````

To me, it looks like a few "dynamic programming" or "recurrence" would do the trick. However, I am only a high school student, no expert in programming.

Is this ever possible?

Comment: Are you okay with using JQuery? If so, you can play around with JQuery Isotope. You can play around with a number of options to customize it - http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html

Comment: OMG This is just what I wanted!! Can you suggest a more lightweight one? Since it still seems heavy. Why not just answer my question? I'll tick on yours~~~  Again, Thanks a lot~~!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can make it more lightweight or customize it but Isotope has a lot of options.

**JQuery Isotope** - http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Also be sure to read the help which could help debug any problem you might run into - http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html

You can also read more about the plugin at Github - https://github.com/desandro/isotope - from where you can also download the minified version of the code.

There is another plugin which is incorporated into one of the layout mdoes used in Isotope. **JQuery Masonry** - http://masonry.desandro.com/. Masonry allows you to plug empty spaces in your layouts by arranging and aligning floated elements vertically rather than horizontally.

Comment: Excuse, but...I have just discovered that, this plugin works in a "_grid_", which means it needs each div's width to be an integer multiple of height (120px as in its example, 150px in mine). As you can see, my divs' width varies. Is that achievable?

Comment: There's an option for fluid / responsive layouts - http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html. You'll have to hack at it bit for your needs but it should be possible.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it's 2338 now in China and I have to go to sleep. I'll review this as soon as I get up tomorrow. Thank you.///P.S.Would you like to go to <www.lrin.tk> to check out my so-said environment?  @sagar